# Doctrine - Can I use mongo hash field to store php object?

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm

Let say I have such document:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as Mongo;

/**
 * @Mongo\Document
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @Mongo\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Mongo\Field(type="hash")
     */
    protected $obj;

    public function setObj($obj);
    {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    public function getObj();
    {
        return $this->obj;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->setObj(new stdClass);

$dm->persist($foo);
$dm->flush();

$dm->refresh($foo);

var_dump($foo->getObj());
//it outputs: NULL
```

The problem is: I was told it works but when I tried it myself I am not able to do it. 
There is not any errors from doctrine or mongo side. 
It is simply not saved to mongo.

I am struggling with it in the [PR to payum paypal](https://github.com/Payum/PaypalExpressCheckoutNvp/pull/11/files) lib. 
In the PR I am trying to add tests for doctrine mongo mapping.

P.S. I know that ORM allows store serialized objects using `object` type. Is there something similar but for mongo?

P.P.S. It does not even work with php arrays.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257660/proper-way-to-load-mongodb-hash-associated-array-mapping-when-not-using-annotati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems in xml mapping. Basically I had incorrect property name set to `fieldName`. Doctime ODM silently skip it and does save changes in this property. Setting correct `fieldName` helps me and `hash` type works just fine.

More details in the commit: https://github.com/Payum/PaypalExpressCheckoutNvp/commit/056d7f2061593cfdf543fd391d73f6a200859dca