# proper way to load mongodb hash associated array mapping when not using annotations with weird accessors

Tags: php, mongodb

I am doing this to map non annotation mapping of my document. But it is not catching it up. I know it is old code, but does someone know how to map it correctly. Thanks!

associated PR = https://github.com/Payum/PaypalExpressCheckoutNvp/pull/12/files#diff-fcfa75e424ccb89d62449aba21f9db31R49

And also related to this:
    https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/MdIoOMWA7F4
    https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/421
    https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/453

```
<?php

abstract class MongoTest extends BaseMongoTest
{
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
protected function getMetadataDriverImpl()
{
    $rootDir = realpath(__DIR__.'/../../../../../../../../../');
    if (false === $rootDir || false === is_dir($rootDir.'/src/Payum')) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Cannot guess Payum root dir.');
    }

$driver = new MappingDriverChain;
    $xmlDriver = new XmlDriver(
        new SymfonyFileLocator(
            array(
                $rootDir.'/src/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/Bridge/Doctrine/Resources/mapping'
                => 'Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Bridge\Doctrine\Document',
                $rootDir.'/examples/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/Examples/Resources/mapping'
                => 'Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Examples\Document'
            ),
            '.mongodb.xml'
        ),
        '.mongodb.xml'
    );
    $driver->addDriver($xmlDriver, 'Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Examples\Document');
    $driver->addDriver($xmlDriver, 'Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Bridge\Doctrine\Document');


    return $driver;
}
```

I get errors of 2 tests failing because there is no persistence of the values properties of PaymentDetail Document under examples folder.

Here is the mapping of the PaymentDetails

https://github.com/cordoval/PaypalExpressCheckoutNvp/blob/mongo-tests/src/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/Bridge/Doctrine/Resources/mapping/PaymentDetails.mongodb.xml?pr=%2FPayum%2FPaypalExpressCheckoutNvp%2Fpull%2F12

and the mapping for the superclass

https://github.com/cordoval/PaypalExpressCheckoutNvp/blob/mongo-tests/examples/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/Examples/Resources/mapping/PaymentDetails.mongodb.xml?pr=%2FPayum%2FPaypalExpressCheckoutNvp%2Fpull%2F12

It seems the issue is because of weird setter/getter of BaseModel which is extended by PaymentDetails.

```
protected $paymentrequest_nnn_amt = array();

    public function getPaymentrequestAmt($n = null)
    {
        return $this->get('paymentrequest_nnn_amt', $n);
    }

    public function setPaymentrequestAmt($n, $value)
    {
        $this->set('paymentrequest_nnn_amt', $value, $n);
    }
```

that above is from an intermediate base class, and here below is from the base class

```
/**
 * @param string $property
 * @param bool   $n
 * @param bool   $m
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function get($property, $n = false, $m = false)
{
    $currentValue = $this->$property;
    if (false !== $n && false !== $m) {
        if (null === $n && null === $m) {
            return $currentValue;
        }
        if (array_key_exists($n, $currentValue) && array_key_exists($m,$currentValue[$n]){
            return $currentValue[$n][$m];
        }
    }
    if (null === $n) {
        return $currentValue;
    }
    if (array_key_exists($n, $currentValue)) {
        return $currentValue[$n];
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this [Payum\Payum#50](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/pull/50/files). I reverted workaround I did for Token document and now it fails too. It should easier to debug cuz there is simple setter\getter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out and fixed the problem. There were several issue I've run into:

- First, After using ORM for long time I was confused that `name` is a field in mongo and `fieldName` is a property name ([issue](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/686)).
- Second, If the `fieldName` does not match any property it is just [silently skipped](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php#L82) (where ORM throws exception). So it was hard to find out why the property is not saved. ([issue](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/685)).

After [fixing the mapping](https://github.com/Payum/PaypalExpressCheckoutNvp/commit/056d7f2061593cfdf543fd391d73f6a200859dca) everything works fine.

Comment: @cordoval weird accessors is not the issue (: